# Dynamically create python variable from input?

Tags: python, dictionary, naming-conventions, dynamic-variables

I'm working to create a win/loss tracker using python, and the problem I'm running into is naming a variable for each case that is possible. Obviously I can't anticipate every case the tracker will possibly encounter (character names, methods of playing, game played, etc.) but I still want to track these things.

I am working to create a variable to store the value of the "method" of play, whether that be character or anything. Is there a way to receive user input and turn that string into a variable name which then stores the # of wins and losses?

I've done some research and it seems that the answer given to many questions similar to this is "use a dictionary", but how can I use a dictionary if I "can't" anticipate the name of the dictionary?

Comment: You may use *the dictionary*, which you can know about, to store what is not yet known. `d = {}; d[input_key] = input_value`

Answer (score 0):

The first step to solving your problem is to define it exactly. An example of how exactly you intend to use your win/loss tracker would have helped clarify exactly what you're trying to do.

You most likely don't need/want to define a variable name by user input to store wins. Rather create a dictionary for each group of associated information (eg records from one user). This dictionary will store the user's name, their win & loss count, etc.

I've approximated what you're probably looking for below.

```
#create list 
gameTracker=[]

#method to get string input from user. Extremely basic solely to answer question. If you actually intend to get user input you'll need proper type checking in these functions
def inputString(Message):
    return raw_input(Message)

def inputInt(Message):
    return int(raw_input(Message))

#Replace "InputString('')" with whatever function is returning user input   
#Loop twice & input records for 2 players in gameTracker list. Each player's records is stored in a dictionary
for i in range(2):
    gameTracker.append(
    {"playerName":inputString("Input player name: "), "playerMethod":inputString("Input method: "),"gamePlayed":inputString("Input game: "),"wins":inputInt("Input wins: "),"losses":inputInt("Input losses: ")}
    )


#Print values for each player (dictionary), from gameTracker list   
for i in range(len(gameTracker)):
    print(gameTracker[i])

#Update the win count for player named 'peter'
for i in range(len(gameTracker)):

    if gameTracker[i]['playerName']=="peter":
        #get new win count- replace with whatever method does this for your application
        newWinCount=inputInt("Enter new win count: ")

        gameTracker[i]['wins']=newWinCount

        #Add one win to record for player 'peter'
        gameTracker[i]['wins']+=1

        print(gameTracker[i])
```

Example output:

```
Records for 2 players stored in "gameTracker"
{'playerName': 'peter', 'wins': 4, 'losses': 5, 'playerMethod': 'character', 'gamePlayed': 'GTA'}

{'playerName': 'david', 'wins': 5, 'losses': 6, 'playerMethod': 'character', 'gamePlayed': 'Zelda'}
```

After updating new win count for player "peter" to 14 + 1

```
{'playerName': 'peter', 'wins': 15, 'losses': 5, 'playerMethod': 
'character', 'gamePlayed': 'GTA'}
```

Defining name of key in dictionary that counts wins via user input (as you requested).

```
gameTracker.append(
{inputString("Input wins variable name: "):inputInt("Input wins: ")}
)   
print(gameTracker[0])
```

Output of above statement

```
Input wins: 5
Input wins variable name: usr_peter_wns
{'usr_peter_wns': 5}
```

Most times defining the key name by user input/variable is not the best solution. Better to have predictable names for easy manipulation.

Comment: I want to define the "method" (character played, game played, etc.) via user input to allow the program flexibility. Obviously a win/loss tracking system is easy with excel for example, but I want to be able to select the parameters of the game played, and then with one click call it a win or a loss, rather than filling in all the information each time.  Does that clear up my intended usage at all?

I appreciate the thorough response. I have this idea of the program being flexible (in its ability to track wins/losses of competition), so I want to avoid hardcoding values as much as possible.

Comment: "I want to be able to select the parameters of the game played, and then with one click call it a win or a loss". So the tracker calculates whether a game was won or lost by different parameters for each game? How would you do that if the variable names are generated?(see Answer update above) I'm trying to help you here but you need to put more effort into formulating your question exactly. What's the context & process? State some specific use cases describing how system should work and outputs you expect. eg player 'matt' playing game 'zelda'..."